# Property of an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space with norm $\|\cdot\|$, let $P$ be an orthogonal projection onto a closed subspace $U \subseteq \mathcal{H}$,

Is it true that $$\|x\| = \inf \{\|y\| \mid x = Py \}$$ for all $x \in U$. I may have found a way to prove it using the Lagrangian of the convex problem

$$\inf \{\|y\|^2 \mid x = Py \}$$ but I am looking for an alternative proof.

Comment: Hint: Any element $y$ such that $x=Py$ has an orthogonal decomposition $y = x + (I-P)y$, and $I-P$ is an orthogonal projection onto $U^\perp$.

Comment: From what you wrote and since $x \in U$ we can deduce $\|y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|(I-P)y\|^2$. hence for all $y$ such that $x = Py$, $ \|x\|^2 = \|y\|^2 - \|(I-P)y\|^2 \leq \|y\|^2$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from basic properties of projections and inner products: If $x \in U$ then $P(x)=x$, so that $\|x\| \in \mathcal P = \{\|y\|: y \in \mathcal H, P(y)=x\}$. We claim that $$\|x\| = \text{inf}(\mathcal P)= \min(\mathcal P).$$

Indeed for any $z \in \mathcal H$, $z = P(z)+(1-P)(z)$, and since the two terms on the right-hand side are orthogonal it follows that
$$\|z\|^2  = \|P(z)\|^2 + \|(1-P)(z)\|^2 \geq \|P(z)\|^2,$$

and hence we see $\|z\| \geq \|P(z)\|$. Thus for all $y \in \mathcal P$ we have $\|y\| \geq \|P(y)\| = \|x\|$, and $\|x\| = \min(\mathcal P)$ as claimed.